Как записать отдельные друг от друга строки в файл? Python
Нам дан файл со списком покупок за месяц. Всего есть 5 категорий. У каждого элемента каждой категории есть цена(сумма, которую потратили на одну позицию этой категории) и скидка. Мне необходимо записать строки с новой ценой(посчитанной с учетом скидки) в файл, но строки пишутся через знак новой строки(каждая string на новой строке, поэтому в файл записывается только крайняя. Как это исправить?
from operator import *
with open('6_4.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    content = content.split('\n')[1:]
    sorted_content = sorted(sorted(content, key=itemgetter(1)))
    in_string = '\n'.join(sorted_content)
file.close()

with open('new_list.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(in_string)
file.close()

with open('new_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    for s in file:
        content = s.split()
        cost = int(content[1]) - (int(content[1]) * (int(content[2]) // 100))
        for i, x in enumerate(content):
            if x == content[1]:
                content[1] = str(cost)
        content = content[:-1]
        in_string = ' '.join(content)
file.close()


file.close() не нужен, ведь используется with, который для того и нужен чтобы сам закрыл

Это не пишется "крайняя". Это вы потом читаете построчно и для каждой строки в итоге перезаписываете in_string. Ну и конечно там будет результат последней прочитанной строки. Непонятно зачем вообще писать в файл, потом читать снова если сразу можно работать с sorted_content

@vitidev, дело в том, что, когда читаю строки в файле через конструкцию content = file.read(), содержимое представляет собой набор строк, потом эти строки через content = content.split() мы преобразуем в список, где каждая строка - это один элемент списка. Когда читаю через конструкцию for s in file:, а потом помещаю content = s.split(), то получаю каждую строку отдельным списком из трех элементов. Веду к тому, что когда список один, то все строки получается записать в файл, а когда каждая строка отдельным списком, то только последнюю. Я как раз работаю с `sorted_content'.

(продолжение), но записать в файл нужно данные из самой последней версией in_string. К тому же из sorted_content не получится (по крайней мере просто) извлечь цену и скидку, для дальнейшей сортировки от большей стоимости к меньшей.

file.read() читает файл целиком, for s in file: построчно. При чтении построчно вы ж нигде не сохраняете результат. Хотя бы в список какой нибудь, а потом "\n".join делать. Так то у вас csv и можно читать как csv с разделителем "пробел", но это ладно. А вот  for i, x in enumerate(content): принципиально лишено смысла - можно просто же content[1]=. И зачем модифицировать массив вообще. Это работает, но выглядит как магия.

sorted(sorted это вы сортируете сначала по цене, а потом непонятно по чем. // 100 не делит на 100

Я поняла, что построчно, опытным путем. В список пробовала сохранить, получается, что каждая строка - отдельный список. И тогда мы все равно записываем значение только последней прочитанной строки. Там, где '\n'.join мы и так работаем со списком(тот, что sorted_content. В sorted(sorted я не сортирую по цене, там  я сортирую по первому элементу, т.е. по категории. Если сортировать 1 раз, то не все сортируется, иногда рядом стоят слова с одинаковой буквой в начале, например milk и meat.

Тогда, чтобы отсортировать наверняка, нужна сортировка сортировки.

Вы не привели данные. Хотя и так понятно что они "milk 1000 20". В питоне элементы массива нумеруются с 0. Так вот itemgetter(1)) - эквивалент arr[1] то есть сортировка именно по цене (причем в строковом представлении) и уже потом идет сортировка без указания ключа (который сортирует сравнивая элементы массивов). Сортировка сортировки совсем не то же самое что сортировка по 2м ключам (типа itemgetter(0,1))

У вас слишком много сомнительных моментов и указывать на неточности можно долго, поэтому проще показать что то рабочее, из которого вы почерпнете нужное.
Не очень понятно про сортировку, поэтому если сортировка по имени категории
и файл выглядит как
name price discount
aaa 90 20
bbb 75 10
ccc 87 11
abc 30 50

то один из вариантов решения такой
1 Читаем данные и сразу считаем
data = []
with open('6_4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    next(f)  # пропускаем хидер
    for line in (_ for _ in map(str.strip, f) if _):  # сразу убираем \n и пропускаем пустые строки
        name, price, discount = line.split()
        price, discount = map(int, (price, discount))
        cost = price - price * (discount / 100)
        data.append({'name': name, 'cost': cost})

или с помощью csv
import csv

data = []
with open('6_4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for item in reader: # type: dict[str]
        cost = int(item['price']) - int(item['price']) * (int(item['discount']) / 100)
        data.append({'name': name, 'cost': cost})

сортируем на месте
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])

и сохраняем
with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(f"{e['name']} {e['cost']}" for e in data))

либо построчно чтобы не выделять лишней памяти (хотя у вас всего ничего элементов, ну просто для примера)
# увы приходится бубен чтобы избежать лишнего \n в конце
firstline = True
with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    started = False
    for e in data:
        if started:
            f.write('\n')
        started = True
        f.write(f"{e['name']} {e['cost']}")

точно так же можно доверить сохранение модулю csv
csv.register_dialect("slashes", delimiter=" ")
fnames = ['name', 'cost']
with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames, dialect='slashes', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader() # если нужен хидер конечно
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)

который влепит лишний \n в конце - такая уж реализация этого модуля (
